# Programatically spread drawn markers around a drawn arc in Android Java

Tags: android, matrix, android-canvas, android-drawable, trigonometry

I am having a hard time dealing with this issue, most of the "help" i have found deals with Trigonometry, which is something I have no experience with. I need to create a view like this: [Proposed Graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyONd.jpg). 
I have the arc and and the background image of the main gauge but I need to add the time markers you see, both the oval like shapes and the times. They need to be added programmatically because the number of markers can be from 1 to 28, though probably not more than 10.

I have tried using the sweep angle to get the X/Y position of the where the arc ends (using division to define an increasing sweep angle to increment the arc) and it sort of worked for the first one but I could not replicate it for any other one with a different sweep angle. 
I am also using a matrix to rotate the marker image which is more or less working, I have been trying various trig functions to get the x and y. Below is some code:
Basic code:

```html
public class Custom_clock extends View
{
    private Paint mPaint;
    private RectF rectF;
    private int mStrokeWidth;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private Typeface custom_font;
    private final int MAX = 263;
    private final int START = 138;
    private Bitmap bitmap;
    private Bitmap marker;
    private int scaledSizeNumbers;
    private int scaledSizeLabels;
    private int scaledSizeDose;
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private String hoursMinsLabel = "Minutes";
    private String hoursMinsNumber = "3";
    private ArrayList<String>DoseTimes = new ArrayList<>();


    public Custom_clock(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    public Custom_clock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public Custom_clock(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    private void initClock(){

        width = getWidth();
        height = getHeight();
        mStrokeWidth = ((width+height)/33);
        custom_font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getResources().getAssets(), "fonts/text_font.ttf");
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.base_arc3);
        marker = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.single_marker);
        scaledSizeNumbers = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.NumberFontSize);
        scaledSizeLabels = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.LabelFontSize);
        scaledSizeDose = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.DoseFontSize);
        int scaledMarginWidth = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.WidthMargin);
        int scaledMarginTop = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.TopMargin);
        mPaint = new Paint();
        rectF =  new RectF(scaledMarginWidth,scaledMarginTop,getWidth()- scaledMarginWidth,getHeight());
        DoseTimes.clear();
        DoseTimes.add("1:00pm");
        DoseTimes.add("2:00pm");
        DoseTimes.add("3:00pm");
        DoseTimes.add("4:00pm");
        DoseTimes.add("5:00pm");
    }

    private void DrawMainArc(Canvas canvas){
        Paint paint =new Paint();
        initClock();
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,null,rectF,paint);
        mPaint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.light_grey));
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(mStrokeWidth+2);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        canvas.drawArc(rectF,START,GetStops(5,MAX)*2,false, mPaint);
    }

    private int GetStops(int stops, int max){
        return max/stops;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
        if(bitmap != null){
            super.onDraw(canvas);
            DrawMainArc(canvas);
            DrawOutlineArc(canvas);
            DrawHours(canvas);
            DrawHoursLabel(canvas);
            DrawDoseLabel(canvas);
            AddStops(canvas);
        }
    }
```

Marker specific code attempt:
This draws the first marker fairly close to where I want it but the rest are drawn up and to the left increasingly, only 2 are even visible. I know the answer lies somewhere with the angle and possibly a matrix but trig > me.

```html
  private void AddStops(Canvas canvas){
        int stopsNum = DoseTimes.size();//currently 5
        int rotatinalIncrement = MAX/(stopsNum);//currently 54
        int markerAngle = 0;
        double x;
        double y;
        for(int i =0; i <stopsNum; i++){
            x = (canvas.getWidth()/4) * Math.cos(markerAngle);
            y = (canvas.getWidth()/4) * Math.cos(markerAngle);
            markerAngle = markerAngle +rotatinalIncrement;
            DrawMarker(canvas,markerAngle,(int)x ,(int)y);
        }

    }
    private void DrawMarker(Canvas canvas, int Angle, int x, int y){
        int scaledSize = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.MarkerSize);
        Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(marker,scaledSize,scaledSize,false);
        matrix.reset();
        matrix.postTranslate(-canvas.getWidth() / 2, -canvas.getHeight() / 2); // Centers image
        matrix.postRotate(angle);
        matrix.setRotate(Angle);
        matrix.postTranslate(x, y);
        canvas.drawBitmap(scaled, matrix, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, `Math.cos` and `sin` use argument in radians, while you (as seems from value 54) apply argument in degrees. Just make `markerAngle * Math.Pi / 180` or use function like `toRadians` if it exists in JavaScript.

Second - for y-coordinate you have to use `sin` rather than `cos`